# Changing the HDMI output?

Tags: hdmi

I need to change the HDMI output on my Pi to one from a desktop PC.
The one from the pc has cables that I want to use. Can I just solder these cables where the original was?

Comment: Without a technical description of the replacement connector, it would be very difficult to answer.

Comment: At this moment there is no replacement connector, I don't yet know what to buy. The only requirement is that it is gonna be mounted in the back of a PC-Case. Any suggestions?

Comment: What HDMI input?

Comment: @Jivings: I think the OP means output. hustlerinc: Then you would need the the technical description of the cable that you want to use. My suspicion now is that you want something like a short HDMI male-to-female extension cable with a panel mount on the female end and a PC case bracket that will accept that mount. No soldering would be required if that's the case (and if you can find such a thing).

Comment: Yes Dennis you are correct, I meant the output, and I thought of what you're describing but having trouble finding it. If it exists I would be happy to order it from the moon even.

Comment: Found this after some searching, seems they exist. Now I just have to find a suitable one. http://www.computercableinc.com/ccinc/products.jsp?sub=HDMI+Male+to+Female+Extension&id=10052

Comment: Thanks Steve, exactly what I was looking for. Please change your comment to an answer so I can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adafruit offers the [cable](https://www.adafruit.com/products/978) you are looking for (a panel mount HDMI Extension cable).